# How to run the servlet program in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans, servlets

I am new to java servlets. I learning from the basic. I have a simple servlet program, but I don't know how to run it.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
{
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
 HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException
 {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println("Hello World");
 }
}
```

How can run the above program in NetBeans. I am using the netbeans6.8. What are the procedures which I have to follow?

Comment: have you read a servlet tutorial?

Comment: http://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/tutorials/introduction-to-java-servlets-with-netbeans.html

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaff.html

Comment: Yes, but they give the procedures for run in command prompt.

Comment: no they don't! You can't run servlets from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you've created a web application project in Netbeans, then you should be able to run your Servlet as part of it.  This guide is for Netbeans 5 but the principles should be still the same:

https://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/1506-introduction-to-java-servlets-with-netbeans.html][1](https://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/1506-introduction-to-java-servlets-with-netbeans.html)

Comment: this page is not found!

Answer (score 0):

The [Java EE and Java Web Learning trail](http://www.netbeans2.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html) should help you get started.